# Is it possible to run a SQL statement when a cell is clicked in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out if I am able to run a SQL statement when a user clicks on a cell in Excel. If so how?

Thanks,

Comment: Use work sheet event to call your own macro with SQL.  See [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17892) for an example of how to use worksheet events.

Comment: @DavidG You most certainly can use excel to run a SQL statement and the data could either be in a workbook or in some other database.  I do this all the time.

Comment: @Portland Runner Hmm I was not aware of this. Is it much faster than using a Find/FindNext combination or looping through variant arrays?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to query when the cell is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Worksheet SelectionChange method and you can do it!

In this following code, the macro runs when you click A1 cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

L = ActiveCell.Row
C = ActiveCell.Column

If L = 1 and C = 1 Then

*(write your code here)*

End if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 
        Call MyMacro 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Then, fire off a Macro to do some kind of import or export.  That's what you want to do, right.  Please see the links below for several ides of how to import and/or export data between Excel and Access.

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?t=envbadac

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm